# windows accidently deleted, ubuntu installation help

Tags: partitioning

i accidently deleted windows from another laptop and only have ubuntu to use on it now, during installation at the partitioning menu, when i click install now it says "no root file system is defined, please correct this from the partitioning menu" i have tried installing this several times and keep facing new problems each time. In the menu i have /dev/sda, /dev/sda1 ext4 118432 MB 2367MB used and /dev/sda5 swap 1599MB )MB used, how do i resolve this from here?

I know nothing about ubuntu at all so an easy step by step would be appreciated

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0GB, 120034123776 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x0003eeed

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sda1 * 2048 231315455 115656704 83 Linux /dev/sda2 231317502 234440703 1561601 5 Extended /dev/sda5 231317504 234440703 1561600 82 Linux swap / solaris
```

Comment: "during installation at the partition menu..". Which os are you trying to install? If you can access ubuntu then open terminal (clt + alt + t) then write (sudo fdisk -l) and paste the output here. Did you delete windows files or entire partition?

Comment: trying to install ubuntu to my hard drive and i deleted everything from windows, i can no longer use windows at all

Comment: Please use proper formatting and copy&paste including the newlines. I am unable to improve your posts. Copy&paste in your question, select it all, then use the `<$>` button in the toolbar to format blocks of text that should be preformatted so it will looks the same as in your terminal. Thanks.

Comment: @James Your question is not clear? Do you want to install ubuntu? Do you need a tutorial for that? or you want to install windows what you have just deleted? or you want to fresh dual boot (ubuntu and windows) system?

Comment: @shantanu im trying to install ubuntu as windows is deleted and no longer an option, ive tried installing a number of times but after install i couldnt download drivers for wifi as i had insufficient disk space, i deleted everything and am trying to use the whole hard drive in order to save the downloads as the space i was using before wasnt enough, so im trying to start a fresh by using the whole of my 110+GB drive, ive sought help so many ways but have had no resolve, im hoping this way is the last try as ive been trying two days straight to install and its becoming tiresome

Comment: @James Honestly, your question list is overlapping a lot and overall not very clear. Always include: 1) What you're trying to achieve, 2) What steps you took and what options you selected in the process. 3) What you're seeing instead (be specific), 4) What else might be related in the situation. In your current question **a lot** of gaps about the exact steps you took are not present. A regular installation does not even show a partition menu for example - just a choice what to do with the current ones. And in others you forgot to include essential information. This is discouraging users.

Comment: @shantanu i want to achieve having ubuntu installed with wifi working, when i download the wifi drives using sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, it try's unpacking but has errors as not enough disk space, so i tried reinstalling using the whole hard drive but i had problems with the partitioning bit which you have now helped me with. Normally after every install i try this SPACE error keeps happening, im quite stuck on how to get around this problem. Im trying every avenue to correct this problem and my questions may seem unclear as im new to this and i dont mean to sound discouraging

Comment: step1: install ubuntu with enough space (at least 30 gb). step2: maybe you don't need to run apt-get upgrade for wifi driver. step3: if you want to repartition all your hdd then let us know. we will provide better option for partitioning. Q1. full hdd space, Q2. want dual boot? Q3. required # of partition for data?

Comment: i have a completely empty 110+GB HDD, i want to use all this to prevent the error message of "disk space empty" i DO NOT want to dual boot as Ubuntu is the only operating system i have on the computer

Answer (score 0):

In the menu that you have mentioned, choose the item(partition) on which you wish to install Ubuntu and proceed.

Comment: i did, and it came up with "no root file system defined..." this happens on every partition i choose?

Comment: Try setting the mount point of any partition to '/' and select that as the partition to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @James choose partition, click edit, set partition type ext4 and set mount as / now click ok